# Partial Build in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have very large maven project which has around 22 modules. Now i have to run 1 module but intellij would build whole project. It is dependent only 2 other modules. Is there a way to stop running whole build just build the dependent module and itself and run ?

Comment: What do you mean by "running a module"?

Comment: Consider each module as an independent component which listens to some topic or queue. Now to to bring up 1 component that i am working on. I am not interested in complete project build.